# Removing newlines from buffer (useful when importing to ORG to unwrap the text while keeping paragraphs)

Tags: text, emacs, newline, org-mode

This function:

```
(defun remove-newlines-in-region ()
  "Removes all newlines in the region."
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\n" nil t) (replace-match "" nil t))))
```

will remove EVERY newline in a text. This is useful when importing to org creates wrapped text. We want then to unwrap the text per paragraph (not in all buffer, which would create a whole block without distinction between paragraphs).

How would we add the condition that if should only apply to one newlines, and not 2 consecutive newlines? Thanks!

SOLUTION: use UnfillRegion. It does the job!

Comment: I know there must be un "unless" somewhere, but I can't manage to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the first newline, you can use `looking-at-p` to see whether the next character is a second newline. So instead of your

```
(while (search-forward "\n" nil t) (replace-match "" nil t))
```

you can use

```
(while (search-forward "\n" nil t) 
  (unless (looking-at-p "\n")  (replace-match "" nil t)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I realize that https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillRegion would be doing what I need. Would your code do something differently?

Comment: My code just fixes your code, which is what you asked for. I have not checked `UnfillRegion` but if it does what you want, you'll probably be better off using that.

Comment: BTW, if `UnfillRegion` works, then you should probably provide an answer to that effect and accept it, so that future visitors know what worked for you.